# running testrunner with cucumber

Tags: junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I am having problem running testrunner with cucumber. I need someone to help me check the @CucumberOptions. Thank you

```
package stepDefinition;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith (Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions (features = "Feature"
                   ,glue={"stepDefinition"})

public class testRunner {

}
```

Comment: Add the problems, what is project structure? For features you need to add the directory path where your feature files are kept like src\test....\feature\. For glue add the package classpath cucumber.test.steps

Answer (score 0):

`@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` is for JUnit integration.
If you want to use Cucumber with TestNG, you have to extends your class with `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests`.

You should have a look on https://github.com/lionhearth/cucumber-testng which is a perfect sample.

Comment: Thank you juherr, i am looking to run as junit and not testng. Thanks for the added information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Test. I have both step definitions/featurefiles in src as packages. Also, i downloaded the cucumber plugin yet i can't see the colors showing in my features. How do reference feature and step definitions @cucumberoptions.

```
package stepDefinition;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;


public class aptitudeTest {

    @Given ("^I have successfully ([^\"]*)$")
    public void I_have_(String str)
    {
        if (str.equals("registered"))
        {
            System.out.println("registered Automation");
        }
        if (str.equals("unregistered"))
        {
            System.out.println("unregistered");
        }
    }

    @When ("^I enter my valid ([^\"]*)$")
    public void I_enter_(String str)
    {
        if (str.equals("credentials"))
        {
            System.out.println("credentials Automation");
        }
        if (str.equals("details"))
        {
            System.out.println("details");
        }
    }

        @Then ("^I should see the welcome([^\"]*)him $")
        public void I_should_(String str)
        {
            if  (str.equals("message"))
            {
                System.out.println("message Automation");
            }
            if (str.equals("information"))
            {
                System.out.println("infomation");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my feature

Feature: Login to account

@tester
Scenario:I should see a message when i successfully logged in

Given I have successfully registered
When I enter my valid credentials
Then I should see the welcome message

Given I have successfully unregistered
When I enter my valid detail
Then I should see the welcome message

Comment: I have resolved the above issue. I found that i was missing cucumber-core in dependency. Also, cucumber-core, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit all has to have the same version. Found this somewhere in another post